# Grails app deployed to AWS throws exception on init

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services

I recently tried to deploy my Grails app to Amazon Web Services (Elastic Beanstalk) but have failed doing so. I believe my connection to Amazon RDS is correct. You can see my config below.  The funny thing is, when I build this project in the Eclipse IDE on the virtual server there are no errors and it connects to the database at AWS just fine.

```
environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            username = "user"
            password = "pass"
            pooled = true
            dbCreate = "update"
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://URLTOAWS/SCHEMENAME"
            properties {
                validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
                testOnBorrow = true
                testOnReturn = true
                testWhileIdle = true
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1800000
            }
        }
    }
```

This may offer a huge clue. Here is the stack trace

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2332)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)

com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:294)
... 13 more

    20-May-2015 04:15:58.434 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root     WebApplicationContext
20-May-2015 05:05:40.300 INFO [localhost-
WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
20-May-2015 05:05:42.273 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
20-May-2015 05:12:15.516 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'lobHandlerDetector' while setting bean property 'lobHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lobHandlerDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```